# A student takes a test with biased assesment and answers randomly. What is the most probable score?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, brownian-motion

A student takes a test consisting of 100 questions in which the following mark pattern has been set:

- +4 for a correct answer
- -1 for an incorrect answer
- 0 for an unattended question

His marks` range is [-100,400]

Which score will the student get with the most probability if the student has equal probability of either answering it correct or incorrect or leaving the question unanswered?

Comment: if you need any more information please comment

Comment: Presumably you are assuming that the student has the same chance of getting each question right if s/he answers it.  Does the student answer all the questions?  If not, what is the probability of answering?

Comment: yes the student has the same chance of getting each question right.

Comment: i dont think you need the probability of answering since we have to count all the cases.( i gave the range as a hint)

Comment: If the student doesn't answer any questions, it is certain the score will be zero, so that is $x$.  If the student has a high chance to get questions right and answers some the chance of a zero score is very small.  We certainly need to know about how many questions are answered.

Comment: these are all the cases.

Comment: case i: he obtains -100 marks. there is only i situation possible in this

Comment: case2: he obtains -99 marks there are 100 situations possible here

Comment: so the question is in which amount of marks will he have the maximum possible situations possible

Comment: there are 501 cases in total. each having a number of situations possible

Comment: which case has the maximum situations possible, thats what i am asking

Comment: We can certainly count the cases, but you asked about probability of getting each score.  To get the number of cases you can just use a generating function.  That is a different question.  It comes out the same if the probability of each score is $1/3$.  Please update your question with what you are really interested in.

Comment: please read the question carefully. i`m asking the marks for the maximum probability

Comment: I did read it.  Not all cases are equally probable, so you can't just count cases to get probability.  Say the student never gets a question right.  The probability of any positive score is zero, even though there are many cases that produce positive scores.

Comment: was the last edit helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is equal chance of each result, the expectation is $1$ per question and we would expect the maximum of the probability to be about $100$ points.  You can get the exact number of ways to get $k$ points by looking at the coefficient of $x^k$ in $$\left(x^{-1}+1+x^4\right)^{100}$$

The relevant section from [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Fx%2B1%2Bx%5E4)%5E100) is 
$$ 9383943728600756091550831937222799535986140850 x^{96} + 9441212767563881641238239559852815864411347000 x^{97} + 9478552294706169386338881965717829092395200600 x^{98} + 9495780838072614943530409908336943990394057400 x^{99} + 9492846052391248917058458350660780465837434824 x^{100} + 9469822329629377911072672009202253792816136000 x^{101} + 9426907986531133506321023335178096900208952500 x^{102} + 9364424524015209542017724007185312818138115400 x^{103} + 9282815226893580956739352008183004513923457800 x^{104} + 9182639181075328076178755591937569123430199200 x^{105} $$
and we can see the actual maximum is at $k=99$